# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop not getting shutdown

Tags: shutdown, suspend, reboot, secure-boot

My Computer : Intel i5-4440 Quad Core on Intel Motherboard DB85FL (built-in graphics).

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from 13.10 through 'Software Updater'. The process was fully automatic and seamless. It is faster than its predecessor with better resolution.

The 'suspend', 'reboot' commands are working properly. But 'shutdown' takes place for a second or two and the system reboots again. Therefore, keeping the desktop always in 'suspend' mode. Please help me.

Comment: This happens to me also. Does any1 know how can we solve it please? Edit: I've just found an answer in a forum: disable "wake on lan" on your bios. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot David for your suggestion. It worked for me now. Let me take the liberty to write here what I did for the benefit of others.

Comment: I have Intel Visual BIOS. F2 > POWER > Wake On LAN from S4/S5. This has 3 options. 1. Stay Off, 2. Power on - Normal Boot, and 3. Power on - PXE Boot. My computer was set to #2, which I now changed to #1. Now it is okay. Thanks again David. :-)